# What is a value of guilt?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-mind, ayn-rand

Ayn Rand portraits Guilt as the largest currency exchanged worldwide. In terms of accounting, and exchanges, daily between individuals; this is a very seemingly realistic observation.

Is there possibly a way to account for or measure the moral value of guilt like other currencies, in an instrumental and extrinsic way?

Examples:

What is the Value of Guilt necessary;

```
For an individual to accept life imprisonment.
For a person to feel the necessity to work the rest of their life for somebody else.
To purchase a car at a lower price.
To take your friend's last piece of candy.
To let them pay the restaurant tab.
```

*There is also the Transfer of that Value and the Relief to be accounted for.
( i.e. The writings of Shakespeare come to mind as a possible base for this type of measurement.)
There are moral value tests, but nothing particularly pertaining to guilt or its weight.*

Comment: You want to create a GuiltCoin, don’t you? Might call them *Dutch guilters*.

Comment: Well, I guess you are conflating poetic linguistics with something it was never intended to be associated with.

Comment: @DanBron haha! Nice play! Just a ledger system to understand guilts affect on an individual's behavior and decision making.

Comment: One take on it: The accumulated history of civilization, passed on through the family, steers you through feelings of guilt. The child begins to develop a superego or conscience. "At the Oedipal stage, the child is likely to introject or internalize the injunctions and demands..." (Stevens) as part of the identification process. So the guilt is an internalized steering mechanism. And it is not all good that this is so, and it is not all bad. "Freud and Psychoanalysis" Richard Stevens, St. Martin's Press, 1983. P 45.

Comment: So the "value" of guilt under Freud's model would be Civilization, but it can cause suffering to the individual, since it is necessary for him to repress the Id. The Ego is like the traffic cop balancing superego and Id.  I am merely mentioning this as one man's model.